# Removing proper English words from tweets in R

Tags: python, r, twitter, text-mining

I'm working on twitter data using R and am trying to remove all proper English words from the tweet. The idea is to look at the colloquial abbreviations, typos and slang used by a particular demographic whose tweets I have recorded.

Example:

```
    tweet <- c("Trying to find the solution frustrated af")
```

After the above mentioned operation, I would like to have only 'af'

I thought of washing the tweets against a dictionary (which I will download) but there must be a simpler alternative.
Any solution in Python would also help.

Comment: did you try using `aspell` in R?

Answer (score 0):

Another hunspell based solution using a rather new & interesting [package](https://github.com/ropensci/hunspell):

```
# install.packages("hunspell") # uncomment & run if needed
library(hunspell)
tweet <- c("Trying to find the solution frustrated af")
( tokens <- strsplit(tweet, " ")[[1]] )
# [1] "Trying"     "to"         "find"       "the"        "solution"   "frustrated" "af"        
tokens[!hunspell_check(tokens), dict = "en_US"]
# [1] "af"
```